# I can't do pagination with while true, not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping, domparser

I'm trying to go next page and for that wrote `while(true)` loop, but not working properly. Giving me no error or anything just nothing.

This is the web site link: https://suumo.jp/ms/shinchiku/osaka/sa_osaka/pnz11.html I'm trying to add +1 to pagination

```
$startID = 1;

while(true) {

        @$url = "https://suumo.jp/ms/shinchiku/osaka/sa_osaka/pnz1".$startID.".html";
        $html = @file_get_contents($url);
        if($http_response_header[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') {
            libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
            $parser = new \DOMDocument();
            $parser->loadHTML($html);
```

And end of the code.

```
$a = $startID+1;

        } else {
            $this->error("Next page is not found!");
        }
```

By the way I am scraping first page with no problem. But it isn't go next page. Any idea for why is that happening?

Comment: `while(true) {` will only ever stop if you break out of the loop somewhere - `return`, `break` etc.

Comment: @NigelRen I checked it out, no break or return touching the while loop.

Comment: You are not incrementing the `$startID` you have `$a=$startID+1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not increment the `$startID` you have `$a=$startID+1`.  So each iteration of your loop `$startID` is equal to 1.  To fix it you need to add it to itself with either:

```
$startID += 1;
//or
++$startID;
//or (if you really need $a)
$a = $startID += 1;
```

And change this:

```
} else {
     $this->error("Next page is not found!");
     break; //exit the loop
}
```

I should mention that `for(;;)` is roughly equivalent to `while(true)` So this:

```
for($startID=1;;++$startID){ ... }
```

Is roughly equivalent to all this:

```
$startID = 1;
while(true){

  ++$startID;
}
```

Except it's much prettier in my Opinion.  I feel like a lot of coders overlook `for` in PHP, the arguments are actually optional, too.

Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks mate, it really helped me out!

Comment: Sure.  Your question was a bit confusing because of how you broke the code up.  What I mean by that, is who knows what happens outside of what you posted, because it's not a complete loop (or block of code) one can look at and see everything that happens (hope that makes sense)